# Akka scatter-gather for string processing

Tags: java, scala, akka, scatter, akka-cluster

I have requirement to split a input string in to output string/s (with some order)
by applying a set of regexs on the input string. I thinking to implement 
this functionality with cluster of akka actors in such a way I scatter the 
regex and input string and gather the string. However I would like to know
while collecting back the processed string, how to keep track of the order. Iam not 
certain if "Scatter-Gather" is the correct approach , if there is any other that 
can be suited please suggest.

Comment: How is the order defined?  Is it based on the order in which the responses come back or is it static and thus should always be the same regardless of the order in which the actors respond?

Comment: its static and should always be the same regardless of the order in which the actors respon

Comment: Can you provide more detail, maybe a brief code sample for how the ordering is defined?

Answer (score 2):

I guess you will have to provide hints to the gatherer on how to assemble the string in order. You don't mention how the order is established: whether the initial split can define the order or whether the regex processing will define it.

In both cases, you need to keep track of 3 things: 
- the initial source, 
- the order of each individual piece
- the total amount of pieces

You could use a message like:

```
case class StringSegment(id:String, total:Int, seqNr:Int, payload:String)
```

The scatterer produces `StringSegment`s based on the input:

```
def scatter(s:String):List[StringSegment] ...
scatter(input).foreach(msg => processingActor ! msg)
```

and the gatherer will assemble them together, using the `seqNr` to know the order and `total` to know when all the pieces are present.